# JavaFX - FileChooser is crashing with a non-AppKit thread error

Tags: javafx, jnlp

My JavaFX app, launched via JNLP, needs configuration from the user to do its thing, so I'd like to prompt the user for a config file before doing anything else.

When trying to start with the out-of-the-box FileChooser (as suggested between 26-1 and 26-2 at https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm), any click on the FileChooser will crash the application with a threading violation. This happens when launched via jnlp, but not from my IDE.

```
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G6030)
Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'JavaNativeException', reason: 'java.lang.AssertionError: Threading violation: not AppKit thread'
```

terminating with uncaught exception of type JNFException
    abort() called

I've tried doing different things with Platform.runLater, including starting a new thread to wait 10 sec before calling it. However, it's clear from the print in the start method that we're on the FX thread.

all-permissions are set in the jnlp

any idea on how to get it not to crash?

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * User: paul
 * Date: 7/22/19
 * Time: 3:00 PM
 */
public class Minimal extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("isFxApplicationThread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
        FileChooser configChooser = new FileChooser();
        configChooser.setTitle("Load Configuration");
        configChooser.setSelectedExtensionFilter(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Ini file", "*.ini"));
        File configFile = configChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(new Label(configFile.getPath()))));
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((x) -> System.exit(0));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

JNLP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Minimal</title>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <jar href="Minimal.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <resources os="Mac OS X">
        <j2se java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc -d64" version="1.8+"/>
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows">
        <j2se java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc" version="1.8+"/>
    </resources>

    <resources os="Linux">
        <j2se java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc -d64" version="1.8+"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="Minimal">

    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```